# Undefined control sequence \likechapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'm trying to make a ToC that would have numbered chapters and other items which would be numbered but would not be chapters.
To this end I'm trying to use a snippet I've found on the Web:

```
\makeatletter
     \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{2}
     \newcommand{\l@likechapter}[2]{{\bfseries\@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}{#1}{#2}}}
 \makeatother 

\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]
{  
       \likechapterheading{#1}  
       \addcontentsline{toc}{likechapter}
{
\MakeUppercase{#1}
}
}
```

which upon rendering leads TeXLive to complain with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\likechapter #1-> \likechapterheading 
                                      {#1} \addcontentsline {toc}{likechapte...
l.331  \likechapter {Intro}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The undefined control sequence is the last control sequence in first code line before the following indented line. In this case, `\likechapterheading` is undefined.

Comment: You haven't defined `\likechapterheading`.

Comment: The problem with snippets is that they often rely on code that is not visible there

Answer (score 2):

TeX/LaTeX complains about `\likechapterheading` as being undefined and used in `\likechapter`, i.e. it tries to expand `\likechapter` and stumbles over `\likechapterheading`, being unknown.

The example should be compilable if `\providecommand{\likechapterheading}[1]{}` is given, i.e. provide it if is not defined already, otherwise ignore the new definition.

Please note, that the `ToC` entry looks wrong from a typesetting point of view (indentation!)

```
\documentclass{book}

\providecommand{\likechapterheading}[1]{}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{2}
\newcommand{\l@likechapter}[2]{{\bfseries\@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother 

\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]{%  
  \likechapterheading{#1}  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{likechapter}{%
   \MakeUppercase{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\likechapter{Foobar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It needed to be preceeded by

```
 \newcommand{\empline}{\mbox{}\newline}
 \newcommand{\likechapterheading}[1]
{     \begin{center}  
   \textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}   
  \end{center}  
   \empline}
```

My bad. That's should be a lesson in attention to me.

Comment: that `\newline` looks wrong to me!